# Bean unknown with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a spring 3.2 project, I am having problems starting an application.
Some bean doesn't seem to be recognized by the system.

I get this error:

```
   27-May-2014 12:41:05.879 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with  name 'reportResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private  com.prjx.domain.ReportFacade com.prjx.web.resources.ReportResource.reportFacade; nested  exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying  bean of type [com.prjx.domain.facade.ReportFacade] found for dependency: expected at least  1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:  {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}


@Controller
public class ReportResource
{
  @Autowired
  private UserFacade userFacade;

  @Autowired
  private ReportFacade reportFacade;
...
}


@Component
public interface ReportFacade{
    ...
}

 public class ReportFacadeImpl implements ReportFacade
{
   ...
}
```

in my application-context.xml, i have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.prjx" />
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component
public interface ReportFacade{
    ...
}
```

can never inject the dependency because its an interface.

so do something like below

```
  public interface ReportFacade{
        ...
    }

@Component
  public class ReportFacadeImpl implements ReportFacade{
        ...
    }
```

then

```
@Autowired
private ReportFacade reportFacade;
```

will inject its implementor `ReportFacadeImpl` .

make sure componentscan inside spring config file has the package entry for interface and class correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined an implementation for your ReportFacade interface.

Spring is no magic. It can't read your brain to know what a bean should do.

So you need to create an implementation of the ReportFacade interface, put it in a package scanned by Spring, and annotate this implementation with `@Component`. The interface itself shouldn't have the `@Component` annotation.

Comment: you have to use @Component on class implementing interface not on interface..see my answer as i have explained there..